# Volume absorption doesn't work

Tags: materials, volumetrics

I'm trying to make coffee cup, following BlenderGuru tutorial, but when I add volume absorption, it only work on top of mesh

[image]

Comment: It must be the reflection of the table on the glass that makes you think that

Comment: oh, crap, it's true, and I don't know how to fix that :(

Comment: you just need to change the lighting in order to create a shadow so that the table is not too bright

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't working, after I change power and position of light

Comment: please share your file (upload and copy paste the URL): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/703f05f068214e668f9985f016a7ee12

Answer (score 1):

The cup reflects the table, that's why you don't see the coffee liquid anymore. To avoid that, change the light strength and position in order to create a darker reflection. Here is a try, here the glass reflects the cup shadow and you're able to see the coffee:

[image]

Comment: Wait, now liquid doesn't have color anymore

Comment: it's a quick setup in order to show you where the problem comes from, you need to make it more subtle of course

Comment: Ok, i still don't know how to do that.

Comment: Could you, please, help, because I still don't know how to do that?

Comment: here is a version: https://pasteall.org/blend/18197d6a166e4d71bd653c81523a582c

Comment: wow, and it was only necessary to change the strength and position of light?

Comment: yes, it may need more work on the material, but here I've just moved and lower down the strength of the light